# How to rotate all objects along their local Z

Tags: objects, 3d-view, transforms

I have 3 objects. I select all, and would like to rotate each around the Z axis of each object (locally) not global.

I need to rotate each object about its local axis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First set the [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html) to *"Individual Origins"*.
Now change the [Transformation Orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html) to *"Local"*.
Both settings are found in the 3D view header.
[image: 3d view header with the Pivot Point and the Transformation Orientation highlighted]

Now when you rotate, either by dragging the blue handle of the rotation manipulator, or by pressing <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> it will work like you want.

Answer (score 2):

There's a button to pick transformation mode, just above the timeline in default view. It will be showing two orbs overlapping with a blue mark in the middle.

Click that and select the "Individual origins" setting (two orbs with individual blue marks).

[image: Transform origins button]

Now every object will rotate around its own origin point.

Comment: David's answer is more complete.